# Is it possible to 'mock' call in android

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, simulation

I want my app to do a 'mock' call in android. This is NOT a debug feature, and I want it to be a part of my final release. 
I read this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9050739/2670775, but it does not say anything about being able to simulate. It just explains how to catch a call.

So, my question is, is there any api or an intent that I can fire in order to make the device 'believe' that somebody is calling ?

The adb has a neat feature that allows us to call using any number. Is the same thing possible from inside an android app?

Comment: That is quiet simple done in the emulator, on a real phone is that impossible without rooting I guess.

Comment: there is no way to , maybe fire some intent etc to do it? if that is not possible, can I access the activity that is launched that while I am getting a call ?

Comment: AFIK there is a broadcast which is invoked when a call is recieved, but you need to be system signed to get it.